# Error gradle when add retrofit implementation dependencies [ Failed to open dex files from /data/app/]

Tags: android, api, rest, gradle, retrofit2

**when implementation dependencies of retrofit REST API get errors**
Error gradle when add retrofit  implementation dependencies [ Failed to open dex files from /data/app/]

```
Process: com.alialfayed.restapitest, PID: 30680
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.alialfayed.restapitest/com.alialfayed.restapitest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.alialfayed.restapitest.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.alialfayed.restapitest-C1XYapOmYMAJ2JGUBBxI1w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.alialfayed.restapitest-C1XYapOmYMAJ2JGUBBxI1w==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.alialfayed.restapitest.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.alialfayed.restapitest-C1XYapOmYMAJ2JGUBBxI1w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.alialfayed.restapitest-C1XYapOmYMAJ2JGUBBxI1w==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.alialfayed.restapitest-C1XYapOmYMAJ2JGUBBxI1w==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.alialfayed.restapitest-C1XYapOmYMAJ2JGUBBxI1w==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
```

When i remove retrofit dependencies it's perfectly work.

** Answer **
add compileOptions tag to

android{}

```
compileOptions {
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

}
and sync app

Answer (score 1):

add compileOptions tag to

```
android{}

    compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

and sync app

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Ali Al Fayed works for me but i place compileOptions inside android {} like

```
android {
....

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

Comment: you could just add this answer as the comment of original answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer does not bring any new information. Please do not duplicate answers. To improve your answers, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).